# Short form for the phrase "organizational matters"

Tags: vocabulary

Does a short form of the phrase "organizational matters" exist in English?

At the beginning of my classes, I tend to write today's agenda on the board. Mostly, I start with the item "organizational matters." It's a loooooong phrase ;) In German, we tend to abbreviate it to "orga". Does a similar abbreviation exist in English?

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Typically ***housekeeping***, or, jocularly, ***administriva*** (*administration* + *trivia*). Though obviously neither is particularly short :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use *admin* for administrative matters.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course...!! Silly me. Heard of that before... Was too much focused on the German expression I did not think of that at all! ;)